# fake_localization tutorial not working in Groovy

Tags: ros, tutorial, fake-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think either PR2 simulator tutorial is wrong or fake_localization is broken
[Link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/TeleopBaseControllerPR2InSimulation)

I bring up PR2 with

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_emptyworld.launch
```

I verify pr2 controller is up by

```
roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch
```

And then try to run fake_localization

```
rosrun fake_localization fake_localization
```

but it gives

```
[WARN] [1358454895.474588813, 112.908000000]: Message from [unknown] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [odom]. Resolved locally to [/odom].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1358454902.814434929, 127.908000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.fake_localization.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[ WARN] [1358454935.913767173, 187.923000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.fake_localization.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[DEBUG] [1358454937.289245561, 190.536000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Removed oldest message because buffer is full, count now 100 (frame_id=odom, stamp=189.477000)
[DEBUG] [1358454937.289406252, 190.536000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Added message in frame odom at time 190.487, count now 100
[DEBUG] [1358454937.289897638, 190.536000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Removed oldest message because buffer is full, count now 100 (frame_id=odom, stamp=189.487000)
[DEBUG] [1358454937.290004351, 190.536000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Added message in frame odom at time 190.497, count now 100
[DEBUG] [1358454937.290251633, 190.536000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Removed oldest message because buffer is full, count now 100 (frame_id=odom, stamp=189.497000)
[DEBUG] [1358454937.290306663, 190.536000000]: MessageFilter [target=/base_link ]: Added message in frame odom at time 190.507, count now 100
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this tutorial not working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52636/fake_localization-tutorial-not-working-in-groovy/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found answer at [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/37908/how-to-localize-pr2-on-gazebo/)

---

Originally posted by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) with karma: 212 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0